# Is there a desktop icon to indicate whether or not the webcam is enabled on Pop!_OS and, if so, how do I enable it?

Tags: pop-os, camera

I recently purchased Adder WS with Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS.  On this machine, there is a hot-key to enable/disable the webcam: Fn-F10.  If I press this key sequence inadvertently, I do not know if the webcam is enabled or not.  To find out, I have to open a terminal window and type something like: ls /dev/video*

Is there such a thing as an icon that can appear somewhere on the desktop to indicate that the webcam is enabled, similar to the icons for caps lock and numlock?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I actually wrote my own capslock tray indicator in bash: https://bgstack15.ddns.net/cgit/keyboard-leds-trayicons. This little project could easily be adjusted to check your `/dev/video*` and update a tray icon, and I'd be willing to help if you want.

Here's another project by somebody else https://gitlab.com/linuxer.gr/camera-control-webcam-switch-indicator, that apparently does more than just indicate; it says it would help you enable/disable the webcam access. I have not used this or tested it; just googled it for you.